# External updater

Tags: vb.net, installer

I've created little block of code that should update a external program, but I've checked it through and have not seen possible error or warnings. There are no errors in my testing but I wan't to publish it so tried to make it as comfortable to many users as possible. I hope that someone could check it too and tell me how they could do some parts differently.

```
Public Module AutoUpdate
    Public Sub CheckUpdate()

        Dim HttpRequestLink As String
        'Change the 'yourlink' to your version text file link.
        HttpRequestLink = "yourlink"

        Dim OlderVersionMessageBox As String
        'Change the 'yourmessage' to your own message.
        OlderVersionMessageBox = "yourmessage"

        Dim UpdatePath As String
        'Change the 'yourpath' to update downlaod link.
        UpdatePath = "yourpath"

        Dim UpToDateMessageBox As String
        'Change the 'yourmessage' to your own message.
        UpToDateMessageBox = "yourmessage"

        Dim ApplicationProductName As String
        'Change the 'test.exe' to your own filename.
        ApplicationProductName = "test.exe"

        Dim RequestFunction As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(HttpRequestLink)
        Dim ResponseFunction As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = RequestFunction.GetResponse()
        Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(ResponseFunction.GetResponseStream())
        Dim NewestVersion As String = SR.ReadToEnd()
        Dim CurrentVersion As String = Application.ProductVersion
        Try
            If NewestVersion.Contains(CurrentVersion) Then
                MsgBox(UpToDateMessageBox, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
                MsgBox(OlderVersionMessageBox & vbNewLine & "Current Version: " & CurrentVersion & vbNewLine & "Latest Version: " & NewestVersion, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                Dim CurrentApplicationPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
                Dim ApplicationName As String = (Application.ProductName)
                If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\" & ApplicationProductName) Then
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\" & ApplicationProductName)
                Else
                End If
                My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(UpdatePath, Application.StartupPath & "\" & ApplicationProductName)
                MsgBox("Updated Succesfuly!" & vbNewLine & "Application will be closed in 5 seconds!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                Delay(5)
                Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\" & ApplicationProductName)
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim ErrorMessageBox As String
            ErrorMessageBox = "Unhandled Error: " & ex.Message & vbNewLine & "Time: " & My.Computer.Clock.LocalTime
            MsgBox(ErrorMessageBox, MsgBoxStyle.Critical,)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub Delay(ByVal dblSecs As Double)
        'Delay Function code by Ashkore Dracson https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXh3Skub198wfTtJCQlR8cA
        'Thank You! <3
        Const OneSec As Double = 1.0# / (1440.0 * 60.0#)
        Dim dblWaitTil As Date
        Now.AddSeconds(OneSec)
        dblWaitTil = Now.AddSeconds(OneSec).AddSeconds(dblSecs)
        Do Until Now > dblWaitTil
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider having a simple text file that contains the latest version number.  That way you could download that small file first, to perform the version checking (without having to download the entire *.exe file)

It'd look something like this:

```
Dim wc As WebClient = New WebClient
Try 
    ' download a text file with the version stamp
     latestVersion = New Version(wc.DownloadString("http://something/version.txt"))
Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show("Couldn't download the version file" + ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
     Return
End Try

If (yourVersion < lastestVersion) Then
...
EndIf
```

If the the EXE file is really big, or you expect that your clients might be on a slow connection, you might also consider using the DownLoadFileAsync method with a progress bar.